# Pagination not working with Loop

Tags: sorting, loops, pagination, wordpress

Page 2 displays the same posts as page 1. What could be the problem?
Below is code from index.php It is used to sort posts by simply clicking on a link such as sort by: "price" or "random".

**Pagination**

```
<?php
    previous_posts_link();
    next_posts_link();
?>
```

**Loop**

```
<?php

$sort= $_GET['sort'];

if($sort == "A")
    {
    $order= "orderby=rand&posts_per_page =2";
    }

if($sort == "B")
    {
    $order= array (
        'meta_key'=>'price', 
        'orderby'=>'meta_value_num',  
        'order'=>'DESC', 
        'posts_per_page' => 2
    );
    }
?>


<a href="?sort=A">random</a>
<a href="?sort=B">price</a>


<?php $loop = new WP_Query($order); ?><?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php    the_excerpt(); the_meta ();?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yourt problem is using a custom query. Why aren't you using the main query. It is totally unnecessary and a waste of resources to run another query here.

As this code is on index.php, which will be your homepage, you can simply make use of the default loop, and use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter your main query before it is run. Doing it this way doesn't require extra unnecessary database queries, and it is much cleaner

So, delete the custom query in your index.php, and replace it with the following code. This is all that you are going to need (and don't abuse the php tags :-))

```
<?php while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php  the_excerpt(); the_meta ();
endwhile; 

  previous_posts_link();
  next_posts_link();
?>
```

Now, in functions.php, add the following

```
function my_custom_query($query){
 if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

   $sort= $_GET['sort'];

   if($sort == "A"){
     $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
     $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '2' );
   }

   if($sort == "B"){
     $query->set( 'meta_key', 'price' );
     $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
     $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
     $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '2' );
    }
 }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_query' );
```

If you, for some reason, need to run a custom query, remember to add the paged variable to your arguments. You can have a look at these parameters in [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

This isn't enough though. You need to set the `$max_pages` parameter as well in [`next_posts_link( $label , $max_pages );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) for pagination to work correctly. You'll need to something like this

```
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $loop->max_num_pages );
```

Comment: Pieter! Omg am I glad to see your solution, in fact, there was a choir singing hallelujah behind me. Ha. I appreciate both the code and thorough/detailed commentary, this is exactly how I want things to be explained to me! cause sometimes reading the Codex is like reading a legal document. Do u have a website or email where I can keep in contact with u? It's hard to find good teachers.

Just one thing, your code gave me White Screen of Death. After trial & error I found a solution. Is this correct? I used 'function my_custom_query($query){'

instead of 'function my_custom_query(){'

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Yes, sorry about that, will fix now. Was a bit in a hurry when I posted :-).

Comment: Fixed, and thank you for pointing out the error. Upvoted you to show appreciation. Enjoy

Comment: Thanks Pieter. Can you email me at my email listed as a comment below? Would really hate to lose contact with you. Will not spam or bother you. Just a hello and to have you as an emergency contact

Comment: Unfortunately I don't give out my personal details. Feel free to post your question here or on WPSE.  I'm always there ready to answer a good question :-)

Comment: Totally respect that. Thanks for replying though!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a custom `WP_Query` and still want pagination to work, you must pass in the [`paged`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#set-paged) argument.

```
// what page is this? default to 1.
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

// "A" args
$order = "orderby=rand&posts_per_page=2&paged={$paged}";

// "B" args
$order = array (
    'meta_key'=>'price', 
    'orderby'=>'meta_value_num',  
    'order'=>'DESC', 
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'paged' => $paged,
);
```

Comment: You'll need to set `$max_pages` parameter as well in `next_posts_link` for pagination to work properly